# Consistency of estimators

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be normally distributed with parameters $\mu, \sigma^2$. Let $cov(X_i, X_j)=p_{j-i}$ for $i<j$. A sequence of estimators for $\mu$ is given by $\hat{\mu}_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$. Show that $\hat{\mu}_N$ are not consistent for $\mu$ if $p_{j-i}=p \ne 0$ for all $i<j$, and that they are consistent if $p_{j-i}\le M c^{j-i}$ where $c<1, M > 0$.

Okay so, consistence means stochastic convergence, that is for all $\mu$ and $\epsilon>0: P(|\hat{\mu}_N - \mu| > \epsilon)\to 0$ for $N\to\infty$. Started with showing the second part, I applied Markovs inequality to get $P(|\hat{\mu}_N - \mu| > \epsilon)\le \frac{var(\hat{\mu}_n)}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{1}{\epsilon^2 N^2}(\sum_{i=1}^N var(X_i) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^N cov(X_i, X_j)) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2 N^2}(N\sigma^2 + M(N-1)N) \to 1\quad(N\to\infty)$.

I can't seem to find where I went wrong here. Is that the wrong approach? Also, how could I bound that probability from below to show the first part?

Comment: You seem to have used the upper bound $p_i\leqslant M$ rather than $p_i\leqslant Mc^i$. Unsurprisingly, the upper bound you get for the variance of $\hat{\mu}_n$ is too large to conclude.

Comment: I estimated $p_i\le Mc^i\le M$, how would I bound it by leaving the $c^i$?

Comment: By estimating sums similar to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^Nc^i\leqslant\frac1{1-c}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $p_{j-i}\ge 0$

$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon^2 N^2}\left(\sum_{i} \mathrm{Var}(X_i) + \sum_{i}\sum_{j\ne i} \mathrm{Cov}(X_i, X_j)\right) \\\le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2 N^2}\left(N\sigma^2 + \sum_{d=1}^{N-1}\sum_i\sum_{j:|j-i|=d}Mc^{d}\right) \\
\le\frac{1}{\epsilon^2N}\left(\sigma^2+2M\sum_{d=1}^{N-1}c^d\right)\le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2N}\left(\sigma^2+2M\sum_{d=1}^{N-1}c^d\right)\to 0 \text{ as }N\to \infty
$$

As for the first part, $\hat \mu_N-\mu\sim \mathcal{N}(0, N^{-1}\sigma^2+(1-N^{-1})p)$ and the variance of the difference does not vanish in the limit unless $p=0$.